# Firebase Server NodeJS failing to connect with Service Account

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a pretty simple NodeJS server that I'm using to monitor our Firebase Database.  My code is basically identical to the sample on the Firebase documentation:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: 'https://myurl.firebaseio.com/',
    serviceAccount: 'path/to/json.json'
})
```

Now the issue I'm having is when I run this code from within our network, it doens't seem to be connection as a have a block of code right after to read some data and it never gets ran:

```
var nodeRef = this.db.ref("node");
nodeRef.on("child_added", function (snapshot, prevChildKey) {
    // ...
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

If I give everyone write access to the database, I can take out the serviceAccount setting on the `initializeApp` call, and everything works perfectly. I've tried running Fiddler to see what it might be making a request to that is failing, but I'm not seeing any requests pop up in Fiddler at all. Any ideas what this might be calling that our proxy would need to allow?

Comment: It sounds like the client is unable to authenticate with the service account. If the issue is security related, you should see an error when the write fails. Anything relevant in the logs? In general it might be useful to enable debug logging (`firebase.database.enableLogging(true)`) and see if that shows any hint as to why it won't authenticate.

Comment: After enabling the logging, its throwing a "Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain"  Any idea what url this might be using that's different so I can have our proxy whitelist the urls?

Answer (score 0):

Our IT team found what the problem was, I had asked them to open `accounts.google.com` in our proxy server. It got set to "allow" instead of "tunnel".

According to them, the HSTS headers were causing the SSL decryption on the proxy unless it was set to tunnel, which was causing the "self signed certificate" error I mentioned above in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

For me, disabling Kaspersky got it to work. You can try that.